# Backbone change event on attribute names containing a space

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

How can I add an event for this attribute name: `Lorem Ipsum`?

I tried

```
this.model.on("change:Lorem Ipsum")
```

but it gives me two events:

- *change:Lorem*
- *Ipsum*

Comment: Ok.. Just found this on the documentation: "Due to the fact that Events accepts space separated lists of events, attribute names should not include spaces." They really should change spaced separated list of events to comma separated :(

Comment: + you just cant name attribute with such name, you will get syntax error

Comment: Yes i can. I'm using it now.

Comment: No you cant - you will get syntax error SyntaxError: missing : after property id. You can open console and checkout this, or check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qDX95/

Comment: I don't use defaults. I've been using this for the past 2/3 months. And this is the first time a spaced attribute name problem arises. Also, i don't use get or set methods because i have a nested (a bit complex) model. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You just need to access your model through this.attributes["Lorem Ipsum"]. Everything else works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in the comments, the documentation states that *Due to the fact that Events accepts space separated lists of events, attribute names should not include spaces.*<sup>1</sup>

However, if you're willing to take some risks on how future versions of Backbone will handle this, dig in Backbone source code and compromise your sanity, you can override the `Events` mechanism on your model :

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    on: function(name, callback, context) {
        if (name!=='change:Lorem Ipsum') {
            return Backbone.Model.prototype.on.call(this,name, callback, context);
        }

        this._events = this._events || {};
        this._events[name] = this._events[name] || [];
        this._events[name].push({
            callback: callback, 
            context: context, 
            ctx: context || this
        });
        return this;
    },
    trigger: function(name) {
        if (name!=='change:Lorem Ipsum') {
            return Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        var events = this._events && this._events[name];
        if (!events) return this;
        var ev, i = -1, l = events.length, args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

        while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args);        
        // I skipped the all event

        return this;
    }
});
```

The idea is to handle the registration and the emission of the event yourself, based on the current implementation of the Events module. You would also have to modify the other methods if you need them.

Setting a `Lorem Ipsum` attribute will then work as "expected":

```
var m = new M();
m.on("change", function(model) {
     console.log('change', model.changedAttributes());
});
m.on("change:Lorem Ipsum", function(model) {
    console.log('change:Lorem Ipsum', model.changedAttributes());
});

m.set('Lorem Ipsum', 'dolor sit amet');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/44m7L/ for a demo

<sup>1</sup> http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes

Comment: Wow thank you very much! This is great! I understand now that it's not the best practice to use attributes containing a space. Some of the in-built functions will not work. As user above stated, defaults function will give a syntax error. I will not use your implementation, it is indeed a bit risky, i figured out a safer solution. Again, thanks for teaching something about Backbone source code :)

Answer (score 0):

LoremIpsum must me a single word.

this.model.on("change:LoremIpsum", YourFunction)

Comment: Yes. Thank you :) Would be great if they could change this in the next versions!